# Having a static class inside Non-static class. How does the memory management happen?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, static, garbage-collection

If you have a static class inside a non static class, how does the memory management happen?

```
public class test { 
    public static class stringVariables {
        // inline code
    }
    // inline code
}
```

Is the GC able to collect the object of `test` class when it's is out of scope? what happens to static class? what are the concerns of using such format apart from static slowing down processing as it is a shared resource.

I think that the first object of `test` class created will not get destroyed unless static class's object is destroyed. This can cause issues with memory management.

Comment: The nested class is essentially just a namespace `test.stringVariables`, it's not a property or field of the outer class, so has no bearing on any instances of the outer class. It is a separate class with separate objects, and gets collected separately from the outer instances.

Comment: what is "static class's object"? you can't instantiate a static class. This doesn't seems like a real/answerable question. There's no objects. Why not write code and debug it?

Comment: Don't nest types. There's almost never a good reason to do so, unless the inner type is private.

Comment: At first I thought you are a Java programmer, but your question doesn't quite match your 8 years experience.

Comment: shingo, this is just a pseudo code for asking purpose. My bad, I should have been more careful.
MStodd - I know static classes cannot be instantiated, but I just meant to ask about the memory that is allocated to the static class, on how that will be freed.

Comment: @jmcilhinney That's a rather blanket statement. I can think of a number of good reasons, things like `Enumerator` and `ValueCollection` classes are nested in the BCL, as well as specialized delegates.

Comment: Lifetime of the static class is equal to the lifetime of your application. Where its defined in a namespace outside of a namespace inside a class outside a class etc. should not matter. The things you reference from within the static class then again have there own lifetimes that might be shorter when you null something or call dispose on them etc.

Comment: Letting aside that the nesting of the classes is just syntactic sugar (as already said by others), there is a fundamental logic error in your question. If X has a reference to Y, there is no reason why X should be forced to have the same lifetime as Y. So even if `test` instances had to maintain a reference to the `stringVariables` class (which, as said, is not the case), that would not prevent the garbage collection of `test` instances. Why should it?

Comment: @Charlieface, yeah, and Microsoft stopped doing that some years ago. It was too late for the ones they'd already done but they generally don't do it with new ones and recommend against other developers doing so too.

Comment: I guess that was the gap in my understanding, that I thought that outer classes cannot be garbage collected unless their reference classes have been disposed. Thank you all for this :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments a nested type essentially is just some kind of a further namespace-nesting, it has no instance-related semantics. So in fact your code would be equivalent to this:

```
namespace One
{
    public class test {     
        // inline code
    }
}
namespace One.test
{
    public static class stringVariables {
        // inline code
    }
}
```

Which apparentyly won't compile, as `test` is ambigious between a namespace and a class-name. However it's for the concept. You can access the inner type via the outer one, e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine(One.test.stringVariables.MyInnerMember);
```

The only difference is, that your nested type can access all the static members within its containing type. However there is a codeanalsyis-rule CA1034, that warns you about having publicly visible, nested types. Type-nesting is more about a logical structure of your types, not a semantics considering in object-instances.

Regarding GC, that construct is pretty similar to as if you'd use two namespaces. As the two classes ton't have anything in common, this also applies to GC. Outer and inner class can be completey independently collected. Instances of the `test`-class are collected when no more references to them exist. This however does of course not apply to its `static` members, which are - as all `statics`s - collected at app-domains life-end.

See the docs for more information about nested types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types